# Are there any virtual printer driver for ESC/POS commands to test while programming?

Tags: c#, printing, epson, .emf, virtual-printer

I am writing a sample program to send raw data to ESC/POS printers (not a specific but printers supporting esc/pos in general) using C# .net.

ESC/POS Command Reference: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=2

So, as you can I am using that above guide to send raw data. But, I do not have a physical printer available while I am coding. So, I am looking for a temporary solution for basic testing.

Are there any virtual printer drivers available where I can send the raw data from my application to and see how it looks? For example: you can install virtual pdf printers etc. But, I need one that can parse the esc\pos and output in either *.pdf or any images or text formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still applicable for you, but I've found this solution:

https://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html

I hope that's something you were looking for.

Comment: I have not got time to test it, but is it opensource and free?

Comment: Try with https://web.archive.org/web/20140124081141/https://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinter_pos.html

Comment: > is it opensource and free?


Current version is **very** expensive (€1000 + €1000 for source code). The older one in @AlesRosina comment looks free

Comment: It is not possible to print to this virtual printer over a Serial Port. :( So unfortunately I can not use it for my requirement

Comment: It should be possible if you share the printer, then add it to a port using net use command in CMD: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=printers-mapping-shared-logical-windows-clients